# Android : screen density confusion?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I've developed a test app to understand android screen density related things. I've values.xml and strings.xml having respective test data in following folder structure :
values\dimen.xml (100dp)
values-mdpi\dimen.xml (100dp)
values-hdpi\dimen.xml (150dp)
values-xhdpi\dimen.xml (200dp)
values-xxhdpi\dimen.xml (300dp)

I am showing these data on UI to know from which folder app is taking data for differetnt screen sizes and densities. So, i'm getting following result : 
[1st device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPE3n.png)
[2nd device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGr4C.png)

Problem is 2nd device with **xxhdpi** is showing me **900dp** value, but in **values-xxhdpi\dimen.xml** value is **300dp**?

Comment: Can you show the code that translate dimen to text?

Comment: Yes. `sb.append("Test Values : " + getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.up_dimen));
sb.append("Test Text : " + getResources().getString(R.string.testing_text));`

Comment: if you want "raw" value for test reasons do not use "dp" modificator, because it is multiplied by screen density taken from DisplayMetrics. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)

Comment: what if i've a textview and i want set is padding according to screen size and density, How should i use vlaues folder then?

Comment: The best approach is making density independent design and try to simplify it. In general - making default value in dp and only tweaking it in "problem" screen sizes. If you want some sort of percent based approach (like padding for 1/3 screen), there are different ways to do it like make it programmaticaly, http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html, or layout_weight in LinearLayout

Comment: have you solved it ? or still there is some issue left ?

Answer (score 1):

900 is a pixels value. Your One PLus 2 have density 3, it means 300dp == 900px

Answer (score 0):

If It didn't pick up the correct layout use values folder like this

- values
- values-ldpi
- values-mdpi
- values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi

  **//added folders**
- values-w300dp-mdpi
- values-w600dp-mdpi

**Add the folders as required**

Answer (score 0):

Sony Xperia J has 245 dpi screen and OnePlus 2 has 401 dpi screen, so there's something wrong with these values.

Densities are as follows:

> - ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> - mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> - hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> - xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> - xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> - xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

[image]

So it's correct that your app takes images from hdpi for Xperia J and xxhdpi directory for OnePlus 2. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html